# Is it useful that $k(X)$ is an ordered field if $k$ either is?

Tags: polynomials, ordered-fields

I have recently found that if $k$ is an ordered field, $k(X)$ is also an ordered field. Proof below, in the proof that order is defined.

**My question**:

I have been never told that a field of algebraic fractions is ordered. Nor in High School or in University. So I have never seen a use of this fact. Is it really useless?

**The proof**:

> I'll use the positive and negative subsets way. So an ordered field $k$ has a subset $P$ such that $0$ is not in $P$, $P+P\subset P$, $P\cdot P\subset P$ and $(k\setminus P)\cdot(k\setminus P)\subset P\cup\{0\}$. And the order is defined 
>  $$x\ge y\iff x-y\in P\cup\{0\}$$ 
>  Reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive properties are straightforwardly proven.
>  
>  It is clear that $x\in P\iff x>0$.
>  
>  We have also that if $a,x,y\in k$,
>
>  $$\text{If }x-y, y-x\notin P\cup\{0\}\text{ then }(x-y)^2+(x-y)(y-x)=0\notin P\text{, a contradiction, so the order is total}$$
>  $$\text{If }x\ge y\text{ then }(a+x)-(a+y)=x-y\in P\cup\{0\}\text{ so }a+x\ge a+y$$
>  $$\text{If }x,y>0\text{ then }xy>0$$
>  Now, assuming that such a $P$ is defined in $k$, define
>  $$P_0'=\left\{ \sum_{j=0}^n a_jX^j: n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}\wedge \big(\forall j((j\in\Bbb Z\wedge 0\le j\le n) \to a_j\in k\big)\wedge a_n\in P\right\}$$
>  That is, $P_0'$ is the set of polynomials with positive leading coefficient. Now define 
>  $$N_0'=k[X]\setminus(P_0'\cup\{0\})$$
>  
>  Now define $P'$ as the set of fractions $p(X)/q(X)$ where $p$ and $q$ are both in $P_0'$ or both in $N_0'$. It is easy to see that the conditions for $P'$ are satisfied, and this completes the proof.

Comment: In fact it is easy to see for $k$ ordered then $k[X]$ is ordered, comparing the lowest coefficients first, and this order is compatible with the multiplication thus it extends to $k(X)$ : with $v(X) > 0$ then $u(X)/v(X)\ge 0$ iff $u(X) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is known, I don't know any interesting consequence of this.

An alternate way to see this is the following:

Assume by contradiction that $k(X)$ is not ordered. Then, there exists rational fractions $Q_1,..,Q_n$ such that 
$$-1=(Q_1)^2+...+(Q_n)^2$$

Next, since $k$ is ordered, it has infinite characteristic. Therefore, there exists some $a \in k$ such that all the denominators in $Q_1,..,Q_n$ are non-zero at $a$.

This gives 
$$-1=(Q_1(a))^2+...+(Q_n(a))^2$$
which shows that $k$ is NOT ordered.

Comment: This is the [formally real stuffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field) what do they mean with using Zorn lemma to extend the prepositive cone of sum of squares to a positive cone (thus an ordering) ? Equivalently how do you know $F$ non-orderable implies $-1$ is a sum of squares ?

Comment: @reuns Define $P$ to be the set of all elements which are sums of squares. If $-1 \in P$, it is easy to see that $F$ cannot be ordered. If $-1 \notin P$ then, whenever when $0 \neq x \in P$ then $-x \notin P$. It is possible tthough that there are some $x \neq 0$ such that $x \notin P$ and $-x \notin P$... A standard Zorn Lemma application shows that there exist a maximal cone $P'$ containing $P$, and for this cone, maximality means that for each $x \in F$ we must have $x=0$ or $x \in P$ or $-x \in P$.

Comment: That would make sense to me : do you construct a tower of quadratic extensions, adding square roots of needed elements keeping the "$-1$ is not a sum of square" property satisfied until you get a field where exactly one of $x$ or $-x$ is a sum of square ?

Comment: @reuns Look at all prepositive cones containing $P$. By Zorn Lemma, this set has a maximal element. If $P'$ is a maximal element, then $P' \cup -P'=k$: indeed, otherwise you would have some $y$ such that $y \notin P'$ and $-y \notin P'$. You can define a larger element  $$P''= \{ p+qy : p,q \in P'\}$$ Using the fact  that $y^2 \in P \subset P'$ you can show that this is a pre-positive cone, which is strictly larger than $P'$ (since $0,1 \in P \subset P'$). This contradicts maximality.

Comment: @reuns Note also that, since $y^2 \in P$, this is indeed some tower of quadratic extensions, which adds elements whose squares are already in $P$ (well all squares are in $P$) and keeps $-1$ outside (part of the definition of prepositive cone).

Answer (score 0):

You have the definition of a "[positive cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Positive_cone)" wrong. The positive cone $P$ must be closed under addition and multiplication, must exclude $-1$ (and not $0$!) *and* all squares in the field must belong to $P$.

In fact, your conditions:

- $P$ is closed under multiplication and addition.
- $P$ excludes zero.

are satisfied by $\mathbb K\setminus\{0\}$ for any field $\mathbb K$.

I don't know if your original statement (the field of fractions of an ordered field is ordered) is true or false.

Comment: With my definition, if f $-1$ and $1$ are in $P$ then $0=1+(-1)$ is in $P$, a contradiction. In fact $\Bbb K\setminus\{0\}$ is _not_ closed under addition. But it is true that my definition is wrong because $P=\emptyset$ satisfies it. Perhaps I have to add $(k\setminus P)\cdot (k\setminus P)\subset P$.

Answer (score 0):

For instance for $k=\mathbb{Q}$, this gives the "simplest" example of non-archimedean ordered field. In fact, for every cut in $k$, there is an order on $k(X)$ or one of its quotient fields such that $X$ is made to lie in the cut.